# Ubuntu 16.04 upgrade issue

Tags: unity, gnome, upgrade, launcher

I have Ubuntu 16.04.  The last upgrade did something to unity.  No launcher, no top menus/toolbars in apps.  Alt-Tab doesn't work.  Cannot resize/move any app window.  Running initctl restart unity-panel-service causes top bar to appear then disappear.  Running unity-panel-service stop/waiting causes top bar, launcher and other things to appear then disappear.  I have read through many of the questions and tried many of the solutions, but none have worked with my issue.  If I can't get it fixed I'll have to switch to something else, as right now it is basically useless to me.

Round 2

Herman, I tried your suggestions, with the same results, except when I ran unity-panel-service stop/waiting, it said command not found.  Based on another question I tried these:
`sudo service lightdm restart`  bounced me to login. no launch, etc.
`unity` briefly caused menu bars to appear then disappear. I did a grep of the unity process number and got this:

```
obiii@Linux:~$ unity
unity-panel-service stop/waiting
unity7 stop/waiting
unity-panel-service start/running, process 6912
unity7 start/running, process 6921
obiii@Linux:~$ ps ux |grep 6921
obiii     6921  0.1  0.1 205512 11156 ?        Ssl  18:27   0:00 compiz
obiii     7046  0.0  0.0  14224  1016 pts/0    S+   18:27   0:00 grep --color=auto 6921
```

It appears that the unity service is running, but that something is hiding it. Also, I have an on-board graphics adapter in a Dell PowerEdge.  I came up with this info:

```
obiii@Linux:~$ lspci | grep VGA
06:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] ES1000 (rev 02)
```

Comment: What is the graphics adapter there?

Answer (score 2):

Dude, I'm sorry to say but it seems like you might have to reinstall Ubuntu, mate.

Do you have access to a terminal? In that case it may be enough to just reinstall the Ubuntu desktop and unity:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
```

Those are the packages that seems to be screwing up. Good luck, mate!

Answer (score 1):

I would have to suggest backing all the data to a cloud or storage device, because the unity package isn't working. Maybe upgrading or reinstalling as Herman Karlsson suggested may work. If not, then get something different, like Gnome or KDE (actually, that might be arch linux)